# Is my php code correct to filter domain / path?

Tags: php, url, filter

I want to everyone can enter a url or domain to database but i want to filter that domain or url with path that real can't come to hack myself so is my code correct?

```
<?php

$url = $_GET['url'];

if (!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
    echo '*error*';
    exit;
}

?>

This is I want [Y]: http://google.com
This is I want [Y]: http://google.com/index.php

This is I want [Y]: https://google.com
This is I want [Y]: https://google.com/index.php

This is I don't want [N]: google.com
This is I don't want [N]: google.com/index.php
```

Thank everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work but it is not a good idea:

http://www.d-mueller.de/blog/why-url-validation-with-filter_var-might-not-be-a-good-idea/

Summary:
There are security issues with this function like XSS (Cross Site Scripting) Attacks which could harm people who visit your site (including yourself). It accepts urls like script alert(123);

Here is a workaround from the website, not perfekt but better then plain filter_var:

```
function validate_url($url)
{
    $url = trim($url);

    return ((strpos($url, "http://") === 0 || strpos($url, "https://") === 0) &&
            filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, FILTER_FLAG_SCHEME_REQUIRED | FILTER_FLAG_HOST_REQUIRED) !== false);
}
```